# How is $G_1 = \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} U^k$ a closed subgroup of $G^0$? for Lie group $G$

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group, and $G^0$ the identity component. 
Let $U$ be an open subset of $G^0$ containing the identity such that $U = U^{-1}$. Let 
$$
G_1 = \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} U^k. 
$$
Clearly $G_1$ is open, but it is also supposed to be closed. I would appreciate an explanation of why this should be closed. Thank you.

Comment: In any topological group, every open subgroup is closed.

Comment: Furthermore $G_1=G^0$.